# How to get current url and add another parameter

Tags: html, url

My url is `https://pc/cid/index.php?schedid=20`.

When I click the link `Chinese`
the url  will become `https://pc/cid/index.php?_language=0`.

But I want the url to be like this `https://pc/cid/index.php?schedid=20&_language=0`.

This is my code so far:

```
    <ul id="head_right" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <li><a href="?_language=0">Chinese</a></li>>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="?_language=1">English</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. First remove the `?` from the href of two li tags.

```
<ul id="head_right" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li><a href="_language=0">Chinese</a></li>>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="_language=1">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then when you click the links, get their href and the location url, concatenate them and append it to the url. So when you click it you can goto the link as you expected.

```
$("a").click(function () {
    curHref = $(this).attr('href');
    url = window.location.href;
    $(this).attr({target: '_blank', href: url + "&" + curHref});
});
```